# Outputs only from bitcoin address

Tags: transactions, blockchain, client

I just want to ask is there any way on how to extract ONLY outputs from particular bitcoin address.
I need to export (make a list) on all address that were associated with the outputs from the sender address.

I have no coding experience at all, I've also come across this topic but I have no idea on how to make just so it will list only the output transactions and not inputs as well.

[How to get the list of transactions of input/outputs for a bitcoin address in JSON format?](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/51794/how-to-get-the-list-of-transactions-of-input-outputs-for-a-bitcoin-address-in-js)

Hopefully someone will be able to help me,
Thanks in advance!

Comment: of course, this is possible. ready to pay for a tool?

Comment: What is the pricing for such a tool? And how does it work?

Comment: I can write such tool. It will parse the whole Bitcoin blockchain (or from specific blk00xxx.dat) and create a list of associated addresses. Mail me if you are interested in.